Open Location Services settings directly on iPhone/Apple Watch using Shortcuts app
I'm trying to open the Location Services page under Privacy & Security settings on iPhone and Apple Watch using the Shortcuts app. I've tried using the following URL schemes:

prefs:root=Privacy&path=LOCATION

prefs:root=Privacy&path=LOCATION.SERVICES



Both approaches open the top-level Privacy & Security settings with Location displayed at the top, but require an additional tap to access the specific Location Services page.
Is there a way using the Shortcuts app or other methods to directly open the Location Services page within Privacy & Security settings?

